# How to set minimum/specific rootfs size in buildroot

Tags: buildroot

I am using buildroot 2016.02 and building for the Raspberry Pi 2.  After I boot the system I have very little free space on /.

How can I specify that I want the rootfs size to be a specific size like 1 GB?

If this is not possible, does anyone know which part of the build process generates the rootfs.ext4 file so that I could modify it?

Answer (score 3):

I found the options under "Filesystem Images" in make menuconfig.  I used "extra size in blocks" and it did what I was expecting.

Comment: This solution seems obsolete now with buildroot 2021.02.2. See the one from @peterh (BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_SIZE key).

Answer (score 2):

```
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_SIZE="120M"
```

Add this line in your defconfig to set 120 MB size, or you can manually change in "make menuconfig" after firing "make foo_defconfig", and before firing "make".